# How to import only one column from a .sql dump in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database dump which consists of 7 seperate tables. In one table, one specific column was reset as i have forgotten `WHERE` statement because i am beginner.

What i need help about is

How can i restore only one specific column from one specific table in dump or,
Is there any way i can do this with PHP?

Please note that dump was exported 4 days ago and there are new rows on tables.

Comment: You could create a new database on the same server and restore your SQL to that, then copy the data across.

Comment: but i only need that column to be restored. In 4 days, so much important data was registered on DB. I cannot loose them. If i can do this by doing what you said, how can i?

Comment: Which is why I said to create a new database, restore into the new database and then copy the data from that one column in the new database into your live database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a new "temp" table and import the data from the dump file (just the records of the table you need to restore).
2. Next, execute an UPDATE + JOIN query on the broken table. The IDs are the same in both tables so it will be pretty easy.
3. Remove the "temp" table.